# Loading different document types in langchain for an all data source qa bot

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to build an application which can be used to chat with multiple types of data using the different langchain and use streamlit to build the application.

I am unable to load the files properly with the langchain document loaders-

Here is the loader mapping dict-

```
FILE_LOADER_MAPPING = {
    ".csv": (CSVLoader, {"encoding": "utf-8"}),
    ".doc": (UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader, {}),
    ".docx": (UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader, {}),
    ".epub": (UnstructuredEPubLoader, {}),
    ".html": (UnstructuredHTMLLoader, {}),
    ".md": (UnstructuredMarkdownLoader, {}),
    ".odt": (UnstructuredODTLoader, {}),
    ".pdf": (PyPDFLoader, {}),
    ".ppt": (UnstructuredPowerPointLoader, {}),
    ".pptx": (UnstructuredPowerPointLoader, {}),
    ".txt": (TextLoader, {"encoding": "utf8"}),
    ".ipynb": (NotebookLoader, {}),
    ".py": (PythonLoader, {}),
 
}
```

Here is the main function-

```
def main():
    st.title("Docuverse")

    # Upload files
    uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Upload your documents", type=["pdf", "md", "txt", "csv", "py", "epub", "html", "ppt", "pptx", "doc", "docx", "odt", "ipynb"], accept_multiple_files=True)
    loaded_documents = []
    if uploaded_files:
        # Process uploaded files
        for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
            st.write(f"Uploaded: {uploaded_file.name}")
            st.write(f"Uploaded: {type(uploaded_file)}")
            ext = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file.name)[-1][1:].lower()
            if ext in FILE_LOADER_MAPPING:
                loader_class, loader_args = FILE_LOADER_MAPPING[ext]
                loader = loader_class(uploaded_file, **loader_args)
            else:
                loader = UnstructuredFileLoader(uploaded_file)
            loaded_documents.extend(loader.load())

        st.write("Chat with the Document:")
        query = st.text_input("Ask a question:")

        if st.button("Get Answer"):
            if query:
                # Load model, set prompts, create vector database, and retrieve answer
                try:
                    llm = load_model()
                    prompt = set_custom_prompt()
                    CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = set_custom_prompt_condense()
                    db = create_vector_database(loaded_documents)
                    response = retrieve_bot_answer(query)

                    # Display bot response
                    st.write("Bot Response:")
                    st.write(response)
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
            else:
                st.warning("Please enter a question.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am uploading a pdf named `protector.pdf` the error I get is

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile


File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 395, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 371, in main
    loaded_documents.extend(loader.load())
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py", line 86, in load
    elements = self._get_elements()
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py", line 172, in _get_elements
    return partition(filename=self.file_path, **self.unstructured_kwargs)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unstructured/partition/auto.py", line 212, in partition
    filetype = detect_filetype(
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unstructured/file_utils/filetype.py", line 244, in detect_filetype
    _, extension = os.path.splitext(_filename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 118, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
```

Here is the full code - [link](https://huggingface.co/spaces/captain-awesome/docuverse/blob/main/app.py)

I am not sure If I am correctly handling the uploaded files.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace - se how to create a [mre].

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut for looking into it, I have updated the question and also added the error trace with link to the full code. Please let me know if this helps in troubleshooting

Comment: Do I have to load the files into a temporary directory and then pass into the loader?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is related to the `loaded_documents.extend(loader.load())` line in your code. It appears that the `loader.load()` method expects a file path as a string input, but you're passing an `UploadedFile` object instead.

In your code, you're trying to create a `loader` instance with the `loader_class` by passing the `UploadedFile` object directly:

```
loader = loader_class(uploaded_file, **loader_args)
```

The `UploadedFile` object is not a file path but rather an object representing an uploaded file in Streamlit. To resolve this issue, you should first save the uploaded file to a temporary directory and then pass the file path to the `loader_class`. Try this:

```
if ext in FILE_LOADER_MAPPING:
    loader_class, loader_args = FILE_LOADER_MAPPING[ext]
    # Save the uploaded file to a temporary directory
    with open(os.path.join(td, file), 'wb') as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(uploaded_file.read())
    # Now create the loader instance with the file path
    loader = loader_class(os.path.join(td, file), **loader_args)
    loaded_documents.extend(loader.load())
```